# Geopointe - Schedule batch geocode run via Apex?

Tags: apex, trigger

After an address is updated, I would like to run the standard Geopointe Geocoder batch job (for the Delta).  Is this possible to do via Apex?

I understand that they offer `geopointe.API.geocodeRecord(id)` but considering it makes a callout it cannot be run directly from the Trigger code itself, meaning it has to be put into a `@future` method.  We may run into the case where the address is updated within a `@future` method so things would fall apart at that point.

Edit: `Database.executeBatch(new Geocode_Schedule(), 100);` does not work.  It throws an `Invalid type` error.

Comment: It is still not clear what would fall apart at that point.

Comment: You cannot call a `@future` method while in a `@future` method so it will throw an error.  It is possible that a `@future` method could update the address, causing the Trigger to fire which in turn has to call another `@future` method.  That would throw an error.

Comment: In that case you need to keep context (let future method know, that it is right in the progress of address updating for concrete record(s) )by static variable. And as far as I understand, in most cases, result of geocoding API should be the same in 2 cases, that's why such a check can be added

Comment: A question: Geocode_Schedule is a managed package class? Does it implement `Batchable` interface.

Comment: Yes, Geocode_Schedule is a managed package class.

Comment: You must run it as: `Database.executeBatch(new namespace__Geocode_Schedule(), 100);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the Geopointe Geocode Delta Batch using apex, use the following line: `Database.executeBatch(new geopointe.Geocode_BatchJob('account', true), 1000);` (where 'account' is the Map Object).  It appears that `Geocode_Schedule` cannot be run directly.